# UIActivityViewController won't post URL to Twitter and Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using the UIActivityViewController to share some text, a URL, and an image to email, Twitter, Facebook, etc.

```
// Define parameters
NSString *text = @"example text";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"];
UIImage *image = self.myImage;

// Create and display activity view controller
NSArray *activityItems = @[text, url, image];
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The text and image appear in the email and get posted to Twitter/Facebook, but the URL doesn't show up anywhere.  Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"];`

Is not a valid URL. It does not have a scheme. Try:

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];`